# Representation theory of truncated polynomials in two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, representation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. I was wondering what is known for the representation theory of the algebra $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$. I think it is clear that there are infinitely many non-isomorphic indecomposable finite dimensional representations, but is there a complete classification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a complete classification.

If $k$ has characteristic $2$, then $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ is isomorphic to the group algebra $k[C_2\times C_2]$, and one place that has a fairly detailed derivation of the classification is Section 4.3 of

*Benson, D. J.*, Representations and cohomology. I: Basic representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 30. Cambridge University Press. (1991).

The classification there also works for $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ for a field $k$ of arbitrary characteristic.